# lldb debug v8: how to get the v8 the type T value of handle<T> type

Tags: v8, lldb

I'm debugging v8 using lldb.

How can I print the string inside of `Handle<String> Source`?

The debug process is as follows:

```
(lldb) r
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = breakpoint 2.1
    frame #0: 0x000000010100536b libv8.dylib`v8::internal::Compiler::GetSharedFunctionInfoForScript(isolate=0x0000000118008000, source=Handle<v8::internal::String> @ 0x00007ffeefbfd4a0, script_details=0x00007ffeefbfd730, origin_options=(flags_ = 0), extension=0x0000000000000000, cached_data=0x0000000000000000, compile_options=kNoCompileOptions, no_cache_reason=kNoCacheNoReason, natives=NOT_NATIVES_CODE) at compiler.cc:2806:27
   2803     MaybeHandle<SharedFunctionInfo> Compiler::GetSharedFunctionInfoForScript(
   2804     solate* isolate, Handle<String> source,
   2805     ScriptCompiler::NoCacheReason no_cache_reason, NativesFlag natives) {
-> 2806   ScriptCompileTimerScope compile_timer(isolate, no_cache_reason);
   2807 
   2808   if (compile_options == ScriptCompiler::kNoCompileOptions ||
   2809       compile_options == ScriptCompiler::kEagerCompile) {
Target 0: (d8) stopped.
(lldb) p source
(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::String>) $9 = {
  v8::internal::HandleBase = {
    location_ = 0x000000010f009a60
  }
}
(lldb) p *$9 
(v8::internal::String) $10 = {
  v8::internal::TorqueGeneratedString<v8::internal::String, v8::internal::Name> = {
    .....
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [tools/lldb_commands.py](https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8/+/refs/heads/main/tools/lldb_commands.py). In short: configure your LLDB to load that script:

```sh
echo "command script import /path/to/v8/tools/lldb_commands.py" >> ~/.lldbinit
```

and then use the convenience commands it provides, the most important one being `job`, a mnemonic for "JavaScript object". It needs the raw pointer value that you'll see as `ptr_ = ...` somewhere in the output of `p *$9`, but you don't need to retrieve it manually. Example:

```
(lldb) job source->ptr_
0x28c008109019: [String]: "console.log('hello world');"
```

(Side note: `tools/gdbinit` tends to have a few more features than `tools/lldbinit`, because most folks on the team use GDB. We'd be happy to [accept patches](https://v8.dev/docs/contribute) to improve LLDB support; relevant to the case at hand would be gdbinit's `jh` shortcut (allowing simply `jh source`) that currently has no equivalent in lldbinit.)

Comment: One more question: It came to error using gdb so that I turn to use lldb. I used `gdb ./d8; set args test.js; set directory /path/v8/src`, then I set breakpoint `b interpreter.cc:268`, but it returned `No source file named interpreter.cc`. Do you know why?

Comment: If you're using a shared library build (which is the default in Debug mode), then that's expected. Simply say 'y' when GDB asks `Make breakpoint pending on future shared library load? (y or [n])`. I start GDB as `gdb -args out/x64.debug/d8 test.js`, I'm not sure when you need `set directory`, or whether it should include the `/src` part, so you could also try dropping that.

Comment: Why is that in some function `job source->ptr_` runs well while in other function it's output is `Failed to evaluate command _v8_internal_Print_Object((void*)(source->ptr_)) :
error: <user expression 2>:1:50: no member named 'ptr_' in 'v8::internal::String'
(void) _v8_internal_Print_Object((void*)(source->ptr_))`( source is the same structure which is `v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::String>`).

Comment: No idea, I haven't encountered that myself.